# Subsets With Duplicates, issues with only returning empty list

Tags: python, list, append, cascade

I am working on a question as following:

> Given a set of numbers that might contain duplicates, find all of its distinct subsets.

You can use the following as an example :

> Example 1:
> Input: [1, 3, 3]
> Output: [], [1], [3], [1,3], [3,3], [1,3,3]

> Example 2:
> Input: [1, 5, 3, 3]
> Output: [], [1], [5], [3], [1,5], [1,3], [5,3], [1,5,3], [3,3],
> [1,3,3], [3,3,5], [1,5,3,3]

My approach is

```
class Solution:
    def distinct_subset(self, nums):
        n = len(nums)
        previousEnd = 0
        output = []
        for i in range(n):
            # judge if the current element is equal to the previous element 
            # if so, only update the elements generated in the previous iteration
            if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
                previousStart = previousEnd + 1
            else:
                previousStart = 0
            perviousEnd = len(output)
            # create a temp array to store the output from the previous iteration
            temp = list(output[previousStart:previousEnd])
            # add current element to all the array generated by the previous iteration
            output += [j + [nums[i]] for j in temp]
        return output



def main():

  print("Here is the list of subsets: " + str(Solution().distinct_subset([1, 3, 3])))
  print("Here is the list of subsets: " + str(Solution().distinct_subset([1, 5, 3, 3])))


main()
```

However, my approach will only return []:

```
Here is the list of subsets: []
Here is the list of subsets: []

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am not sure why did I go wrong. The algorithm supposes to update the output in each iteration. But now it failed.

Please feel free to share your ideas. Thanks for your help in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I ran your code and it appears no matter what you do the function will always return an output of an empty list, because nothing is actually changing in the list, it is always blank.

Forgive me, but I had to look up what 'all distinct subsets' meant, and I stumbled across this code, but it seems to do exactly what you are asking.

```
# Python3 program to find all subsets of  
# given set. Any repeated subset is  
# considered only once in the output 
def printPowerSet(arr, n): 
      
    # Function to find all subsets of given set. 
    # Any repeated subset is considered only  
    # once in the output 
    _list = [] 
  
    # Run counter i from 000..0 to 111..1 
    for i in range(2**n): 
        subset = "" 
  
        # consider each element in the set 
        for j in range(n): 
  
            # Check if jth bit in the i is set.  
            # If the bit is set, we consider  
            # jth element from set 
            if (i & (1 << j)) != 0: 
                subset += str(arr[j]) + "|"
  
        # if subset is encountered for the first time 
        # If we use set<string>, we can directly insert 
        if subset not in _list and len(subset) > 0: 
            _list.append(subset) 
  
    # consider every subset 
    for subset in _list: 
  
        # split the subset and print its elements 
        arr = subset.split('|') 
        for string in arr: 
            print(string, end = " ") 
        print() 
  
# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    arr = [10, 12, 12, 17] 
    n = len(arr) 
    printPowerSet(arr, n)
```

However, as you can see the above code does not use classes just a single function. If that works great, if you are required to use a class, let me know you will need to change the above code obviously.

Comment: Oh also, let me know if that did not in fact answer your question, I noticed the above code answers a question phrased slightly different, but I think it is the same idea.

Comment: Appreciate your work. I have updated my question with an example. I hope this will help you to understand the question. And would you mind telling why my program will keep returning the original output list with `[]`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the below is what you are looking for:

```
[1, 3, 3] to [1,3]
[1, 5, 3, 3] to [1,5,3]
```

The `set(list)` function will do that for you real easy, however it doesn't handle compound data structure well.

Below code will work for compound data from, one level deep:

```
[[1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

to:

```
[[1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0]]
```

code:

```
def get_unique(list):
    temp = []
    for i in list:
        if i not in temp:
            temp.append(i)
            yield i
print(*get_unique(list))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jay. In my question, you still need to consider the duplicate case, rather than simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I've trimmed the above code to give you your desired outputs, still not in a class though, is this okay?...

```
def distinct_subset(user_input):
    n = len(user_input)
    output = []
    for i in range(2 ** n):
        subset = ""
        for j in range(n):
            if (i & (1 << j)) != 0:
                subset += str(user_input[j]) + ", "
        if subset[:-2] not in output and len(subset) > 0:
            output.append(subset[:-2])
    return output


def main():

    print("Here is the list of subsets: " + str(distinct_subset([1, 3, 3])))
    print("Here is the list of subsets: " + str(distinct_subset([1, 5, 3, 3])))


main()
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Would you mind explaining a little bit more? Are you able to find that why my code is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for distinct combinations of the powerset of your list.

Using itertools to generate the combinations and a set to eliminate duplicates, you could write the function like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
def uniqueSubsets(A):
    A = sorted(A)
    return [*map(list,{subset for size in range(len(A)+1) 
                              for subset in combinations(A,size)})]

print(uniqueSubsets([1,3,3]))
# [[1, 3], [3, 3], [1], [3], [], [1, 3, 3]]

print(uniqueSubsets([1,5,3,3]))
# [1, 3] [3, 3] [1] [3] [3, 3, 5] [1, 3, 5] [1, 5] [5] [] [1, 3, 3, 5] [1, 3, 3] [3, 5]
```

If you have a lot of duplicates, it may be more efficient to filter them out as you go.  Here is a recursive generator function that short-circuits the expansion when a combination has already been seen.  It generates combinations by removing one element at a time (starting from the full size) and recursing to get shorter combinations.

```
def uniqueSubsets(A,seen=None):
    if seen is None: seen,A = set(),sorted(A)  
    for i in range(len(A)):         # for each position in the list
        subset = (*A[:i],*A[i+1:])  # combination without that position
        if subset in seen: continue # that has not been seen before
        seen.add(subset)
        yield from uniqueSubsets(subset,seen) # get shorter combinations
    yield list(A)

print(*uniqueSubsets([1,3,3]))
# [] [3] [3, 3] [1] [1, 3] [1, 3, 3]

print(*uniqueSubsets([1,5,3,3]))
# [] [3] [3, 3] [5] [5, 3] [5, 3, 3] [1] [1, 3] [1, 3, 3] [1, 5] [1, 5, 3] [1, 5, 3, 3]
```

*In both cases we are sorting the list in order to ensure that the combinations will always present the values in the same order for the set() to recognize them. (otherwise lists such as [3,3,1,3] could still produce duplicates)*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Would you mind explaining your first approach a little bit more? I still tried to figure out your second approach. My background is statistician, so that my Python coding is not that strong. Haha.

Comment: A powerset for N elements if the union of all combinations of 0, 1, 2, ... N elements.  The list comprehension in the first solution goes through all sizes `size in range(len(A)+1)` and, for each size it uses the `combinations` function to get every combination of that length.  You can read that list comprenension as nested for loop that does an append() to the resulting list.